# Need help creating a BarChart

Tags: date-and-time, charts

I have a [log-file](https://pastebin.com/raw/dwJAcAMi) which lists a time and date I logged in on one website. I want to create a `BarChart` which compares the amount of times I did it every day. How to I make *Mathematica* count the amount of times, when I logged in on a certain day?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `DateHistogram` for this:

```
logs = Import["~/Downloads/dat1.csv"];
logs = Rest[logs]; (* drop the headers *)
```

This bit may look a bit complicated, but it's just combining the date and time strings and converting them to a `DateObject`, with some help about how they're formatted:

```
times = DateObject[{# <> " " <> #2, {"MonthShort", "DayShort", 
       "YearShort", "Hour24", "Minute"}}] & @@@ logs;
```

Create a histogram, with one bin for each day:

```
DateHistogram[times, "Day", DateTicksFormat -> {"MonthShort", "/", "Day"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
summary = Length /@ SemanticImport["C:/temp/temp.csv"][GroupBy["Date"]]
BarChart[summary, ChartLabels -> Keys@Normal@summary,  ImageSize -> Large]
```

You can play with the labels as much as you wish.  E.g.,

```
labels = DateString[#, {"MonthNameShort", "-", "Day"}] & /@ Keys@Normal@summary
BarChart[summary, ChartLabels -> labels]
```